# Unable to Boot Raspberry Pi (Constant Red Light)

Tags: boot, boot-issues, pi-5

I recently bought Raspberry Pi 5 and am not able to boot it. On connecting the power cable, I get a constant red light. At no point do I see a green light after pressing the power button.

Setup:

1. Installed Raspberry Pi OS on a 32 GB SD card (SanDisk Ultra) via Raspberry Pi Imager.
2. Connected a monitor via micro-HDMI cable.
3. Connected wired keyboard and mouse via USB

Troubleshooting till now:

1. HDMI cable is okay as monitor does not show "Cable is not connected."
2. Tried reflashing the OS using Raspberry Pi Imager.
3. Installed the image on a different SD card
4. Used various power sources (22W adapter, 40W adapter, 20W Power bank)

Is there anything else that I can try to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: perhaps you have a faulty SD card slot on the pi - you could try booting from a usb thumb drive - though I would've thought you'd get some output on the monitor